# mysql get latest date record in ascending order

Tags: php, mysql

I have following "stats" table:

[image]

I want mysql query that return latest 5 date with sum of clicks. So starting record should be 2015-01-12

Output:

[image]

So far i have written following query that doesn't work according to my output.

```
SELECT logdate, (
    SELECT SUM(clicks)
    FROM stats t2
    WHERE t2.logdate = t1.logdate
    ORDER BY t2.logdate
    DESC LIMIT 0,5
) as clicks
FROM stats t1
GROUP BY t1.logdate
ORDER BY t1.logdate ASC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why such a complicated query? You can simply do

```
SELECT logdate,sum(clicks) FROM stats
GROUP BY logdate 
ORDER BY logdate DESC
LIMIT 5
```

**Edit after your comment**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT logdate,sum(clicks) FROM stats
 GROUP BY logdate 
 ORDER BY logdate DESC
 LIMIT 5
) data
 ORDER BY logdate ASC
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d7a2c/1)**

Comment: It returns latest date record on top.. I want your query output in reverse order.

Comment: You can wrap another select around the result to sort the dates ascending, see the edit